# Why messages received from an asyncio.Queue don't keep the order they were sent in?

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, publish-subscribe

I'm struggling to keep the correct order of messages received from an `asyncio.Queue`.

In my case, multiple publishers (which `put` messages to the queue) send messages to a consumer (which `get`s the messages from the queue) through a single `asyncio.Queue`. In the sample code below, the assertions in the `consumer.process` don't hold, i.e., the order of the received messages is violated:

```py
import asyncio
import random


async def publish(publisher_id, consumer_queue, messages):
    assert messages == sorted(messages)  # sent messages are ordered
    for message in messages:
        if random.random() < 0.1:  # simulate publisher taking a short break
            await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        # publish message to queue
        asyncio.create_task(consumer_queue.put((publisher_id, message)))
    # signal that this publisher is finished
    asyncio.create_task(consumer_queue.put((publisher_id, None)))


class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, num_publishers):
        self.publishers = {publisher: [] for publisher in range(num_publishers)}
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=1)
        self.finished = asyncio.Event()

    async def consume_loop(self):
        while True:
            publisher_id, message = await self.queue.get()
            # delegate processing of the message
            asyncio.create_task(self.process(publisher_id, message))

    async def process(self, publisher_id, message):
        if message is None:  # publisher is finished
            received = self.publishers.pop(publisher_id)
            # assert that if messages sent by a publisher are ordered,
            # then the same messages received by the consumer are also ordered
            assert received == sorted(received), f'{publisher_id}: {received}'
            if not self.publishers:
                # all publishers are finished
                self.finished.set()
        else:
            # assert that the publisher is still publishing
            assert publisher_id in self.publishers, publisher_id
            self.publishers[publisher_id].append(message)


async def main():
    num_publishers = 100
    consumer = Consumer(num_publishers)
    # consumer begins listening for new messages
    asyncio.create_task(consumer.consume_loop())
    # create publishers that send messages to the consumer
    for publisher_id in range(num_publishers):
        messages = list(range(100))
        asyncio.create_task(publish(publisher_id, consumer.queue, messages))
    # wait for the consumer to receive all messages
    await consumer.finished.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Observations:

- If the publishers don't take a break, the assertions hold. However, in my use case, publishers don't instantly publish all messages, but rather publish messages occasionally.
- If an unbounded queue is used instead of bounded, the assertions hold. However, I want the queue to be bounded to apply some backpressure to the publishers.
- The ordering does not break for all publishers.
- The more publishers/messages, the more likely it is for the assertions to break.
- Assertions break even if `consumer.process` is not asynchronous.

Questions (important are bold):

- Is the ordering of messages bugged in the `asyncio.Queue` code?
- Am I wrong to assume that in my case, `asyncio.Queue` should also operate on FIFO principle for each individual publisher?
- Is this behaviour connected to some ordering problems in the `asyncio` code due to the number of created tasks? I think not, since unbounded queue works fine.
- **How to retain the ordering while keeping the queue bounded?**
- **If the problem is that many publishers use the same queue, are there any queue implementations that work for multiple publishers?**

Comment: You are not applying backpressure because you call `create_task(self.process(...))` instead of `await self.process(...)`. You just move the unbounded queue from your bounded explicit queue to the unbounded queue of tasks maintained by the event loop. Additionally, the order of these tasks is not guaranteed. Is there a reason why you call `create_task()` to process the publisher_id without waiting for it?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are completely right about the backpressure part. It should've been `await self.process(...)`. In general, I'm using `create_task()` because I want to separate message passing and message processing. The reason is that publishers are also busy with other jobs. They can't wait for the consumers to process the messages. Instead, they send messages in a "fire & forget" fashion. So basically, if I keep using the fire & forget approach, I cannot ensure the right order of processed messages, unless I buffer the messages in the consumer, e.g. by using an unbounded queue?

Comment: If producers can't wait for the consumer to process the messages, then you can't really do backpressure, either. (Waiting for consumers is pretty much the definition of backpressure.) Without backpressure, you can just use an unbounded queue, and use `await self.process(...)` in the consumer. Since the queue is FIFO, the original order will be respected.

Comment: I see. You are right, doing backpressure doesn't make sense here. So your solution answers my original question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio.Queue` is first-in first-out, which means items are dequeued in the same order in which they were enqueued. The problem with your code is that it the consumer doesn't await the processing code, but spawns it to run in the background. Also, the producers don't await enqueueing, but run that in the background as well.

The consequence is that no backpressure is being applied because, while the queue is technically bounded, the items are dequeued as soon as they appear, and they are transferred to the (unbounded) queue of tasks internally maintained by the event loop. Also, you lose ordering because `create_task()` are not guaranteed to run in a particular order.

To fix this, you should:

- make your queue unbounded,
- change `asyncio.create_task(consumer_queue.put(...))` to `await consumer_queue.put(...)`, and
- change `asyncio.create_task(self.process(...))` to `await self.process(...)`.

If you decide you do need backpressure, make the channel bounded.